# Using attributes in protractor test case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a piece of code in the angular app that looks like this, It looks like a button but in the command there is no button text.

```html
 <a href="#/pages/master?chat=P10&amp;key=10" class="btn btn-primary">Go to this node</a>
```

I'm trying t use this command to do the click but it doe snot work

```js
element(by.css('a[href="#/pages/master?chat=P10&amp;key=10"]')).click();
```

But I get error and wait for the locator to find and do the click.

Anyone having any other idea, can xpath be used somehow as there is not span or input?

Comment: Can you add HTML of neighboring elements too .. This button should be part of a `form` or `div may be?

Answer (score 1):

you can also select it by text with:

```
element(by.linkText("Go to this node")).click();
```